# Syntax highlighting for C doesn't properly recognize `restrict` as a keyword

Tags: feature-request, syntax-highlighting

And while we're at it, C11 adds some keywords like `_Atomic` as well.
Is this the right way to submit requests for addition, or would it be better to ask for it in the 'Google Code Prettify' project?

EDIT: I checked the prettify source repository (read-only, svn revision 194), and would suggest to change the variable `C_KEYWORDS` in src/prettify.js, line 70, to:

```
var C_KEYWORDS = [FLOW_CONTROL_KEYWORDS,"auto,case,char,const,default," + 
    "double,enum,extern,float,goto,int,long,register,short,signed,sizeof," +
    "static,struct,switch,typedef,union,unsigned,void,volatile," +
    "_Alignas,_Alignof,_Atomic,_Bool,_Complex,_Generic,_Imaginary," +
    "_Noreturn,_Static_assert,_Thread_local,inline,restrict"];
```

Especially `inline` and `restrict` are omissions from C99.
If you wish, you might also include the more common variants (but formally not defined as keywords):

```
var C_KEYWORDS = [FLOW_CONTROL_KEYWORDS,"auto,case,char,const,default," + 
    "double,enum,extern,float,goto,int,long,register,short,signed,sizeof," +
    "static,struct,switch,typedef,union,unsigned,void,volatile," +
    "_Alignas,_Alignof,_Atomic,_Bool,_Complex,_Generic,_Imaginary," +
    "_Noreturn,_Static_assert,_Thread_local,inline,restrict," +
    "alignas,alignof,atomic,bool,complex,generic,imaginary," +
    "noreturn,static_assert,thread_local"];
```

Refer to the most recent C standard ISO/IEC 9899:2011 for details.

EDIT2: I sent an email to the author of prettify as well.

Comment: Can you link to some questions/answers that use these keywords?

Comment: @BilltheLizard My own post :) http://stackoverflow.com/q/8989243/1029106

Comment: *"Is this the right way to submit requests for addition, or would it be better to ask for it in the 'Google Code Prettify' project?"* Both!

Comment: @AdamDavis It appears that you need a Google account to post in that forum, and also to generate a new issue. I do not have an account, so maybe someone with an account is kind enough to create an issue in the list. A [list with all C and C++ keywords](http://www.bezem.de/pdf/ReservedWordsInC.pdf) until C11 and C++11 can be found at my website, if necessary.

Comment: @BilltheLizard Email sent to Mike Samuel.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The right thing to do is:

1. *Submit a patch to [the google-code-prettify project](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify)*.

   One way to do this is to first edit the JavaScript live (e.g. in the Chrome Inspector), then open the relevant file under http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/source/browse/trunk/src, click "Edit file", make the same change there, and submit it with an appropriate description.
2. *When that patch is accepted, request that prettify be updated on SE*.

   This part you can do by posting a "question" here on meta.SO. Something like "Please update prettify to > r9000 so we can have proper spiky-hair support" might be a good title.