# Syntax Highlighting Doesn't Recognize Line Continuations Within VB6 Comments

Tags: bug, syntax-highlighting

I've run into some unexpected syntax highlighting mistakes while I [was asking a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9172747/a-solution-for-unready-drives-in-vb6) about VB6.

When I use `_` after using `'` to add comments about my code I see that `_` does not work within `'`, but it should.

Here is a screenshot demonstrating the situation:

> [image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Stack Exchange sites are using [Google Code Prettify](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/) JavaScript module to have those nice colors, so that's actually a problem/bug with "their" code.

Similar case has already been reported:
[Syntax highlighting for C doesn't properly recognize `restrict` as a keyword](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120169/syntax-highlighting-for-c-doesnt-properly-recognize-restrict-as-a-keyword)

(Similar in the sense of problem with Prettify)

Comment: i see now, ty for leading me to the right direction.

Answer (score 5):

This is fixed in prettify at [revision 203](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/source/detail?r=203#).  A new release will be forthcoming soon.

Comment: thanks i cant wait for the new release.