# Highlighter inconsistency with #includes

Tags: support, syntax-highlighting

I have noticed that in some cases that highlighter uses different colors to semantically identical pieces of code, namely include statements:

[image]

This is a screenshot of the following answer: [How to execute a functor or a lambda in a given thread in Qt, GCD-style?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21646467/140367)

My [test answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox/220233#220233) in the formatting sandbox suggests that it depends only on the capitalization of the include file name.

Comment: I fear it's not in SE hands, at least not directly. See [this other answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/120785/152859).