# My question is marked 'duplicate' because of a later Wiki post - do I remove my question?

Tags: discussion

I asked a [question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120169/syntax-highlighting-for-c-doesnt-properly-recognize-restrict-as-a-keyword) on a specific issue with syntax-highlighting in January 2012. Got my answer, marked it, all was fine.
In June 2013 a [question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work) was asked, much broader, and made into 'Community Wiki'.
And now, my question has been flagged 'duplicate' shortly after that. In my opinion it isn't quite, but I can understand why.

What should I do now? Delete my question? I cannot really see an edit modifying my question, I could explain why the Wiki entry doesn't quite fit the bill.
And it seems a little unfair to me, to 'deserve' a duplicate sign, even if the Wiki entry didn't exist when the question was asked. But that's just a little pride hurt, nothing much...

Comment: Don't consider the duplicate mark a bad thing, its not like other closures. Even had you have asked the question later limited duplication is still useful. However if its an invalid duplicate then comment/edit to make that clear

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't do anything.  There's no need to delete the question, not that you could even if you tried.

As for what should be closed as a duplicate of what, it doesn't matter which question was asked first, rather whichever question/answer is of the highest quality, and will serve as a better canonical reference is the one that should remain open.